# Install font in latex results in invisible text when compiling with ‘latex’

Tags: fonts, installing

I tried installing the nimbus font (http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/urwvf/) in my local texmf tree by following the README provided with the package (and also on the website above). However, after installing and using the package, all characters are invisible in my document when I use 'latex' to compile the document. When I use 'pdflatex' it works. What could be the reason for it, not working with 'latex'?

Comment: Provide us with more information: are there any errors in the logfile? Which dvi viewer are you using? I'd guess that the dvi software is generating errors. Can you post them in your question?